# How to run react-native server?

Tags: swift, react-native

(JS_DIR=`pwd`/ReactComponent; cd Pods/React; npm run start -- --root $JS_DIR)

But, I can't find the Pods/React in the directory.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB0oT.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just `npm install -g react-native-cli` and then run `react-native start` in your project directory.

Comment: Thanks.But how to appoint the directory of JavaScript file where in ReactComponet folder. Sorry I got a broken english.

Comment: Just `cd path/to/project` first before you run `react-native start`.